# List of contact, need to display each contact in letter category

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of contact that look like this:

```
contacts = [{ name: 'Albert' }, { name:'Bernard' }, { name: 'Bob'}, { name: 'Robert' }];
```

Considering the contacts are already ordered alphabetically, how would you go about display each of them in a list categorized by letter like so:

A

- Albert

B

- Bernard
- Bob

R

- Robert

In my template I know how to display my contacts already

```
<template v-for="contact in contacts">
 <li>{{ contact.name }}</li>
<template>
```

But I have no idea how to go about the letter categorizing

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a library like [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) and a computed property:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            contacts: [{ name: 'Albert' }, { name:'Bernard' }, { name: 'Bob'}, { name: 'Robert' }]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        grouped () {
            return _.groupBy(this.contacts, (item) => {
                return item.name.charAt(0)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the template:

```html
<div v-for="(value, key) in grouped">
    <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="contact in value">{{ contact.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me @Hammerbot how can we sort this array base on the aliphatic index?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to group those items by the first letter in another array, and push the items accordingly.

You can do this using a computed property so the data is always updated automatically.

See:

```js
var contacts = [{name: 'Albert'}, {name: 'Amanda'}, {name: 'Bernard'}, {name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Robert'}];

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#contact-list',
  data: {
    contacts: contacts
  },
  computed: {
    groupedContacts: function() {
      var groups = {};
      
      //Loops every contact
      this.contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
        //Gets the contact's first char in the contact's name
        var firstLetter = contact.name.charAt(0);
        //Checks if the 'groups' object contains the key for the contact's first letter
        if (!groups[firstLetter]) {
          //If it doesn't, creates it as an empty array.
          groups[firstLetter] = [];
        }
        
        var entry = groups[firstLetter];
        //Adds the contact to the group
        entry.push(contact);
      });
      return groups;
    }
  }
});

console.log(app.groupedContacts);
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<div id="contact-list">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(group, key) in groupedContacts">
      {{key}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="contact in group">
          {{contact.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also use `reduce` [(jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/m5bnrp1o/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a method to return a filtered list. First, here is my front end:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    contacts: [{
      name: 'Albert'
    }, {
      name: 'Bernard'
    }, {
      name: 'Bob'
    }, {
      name: 'Robert'
    }],
    letters: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
  },
  methods: {
    alphaContacts: function(l) {
      return this.contacts.filter(i => {
        return i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(l.toLowerCase()) === 0;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="letter in letters">
    <h1>{{letter}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="contact in alphaContacts(letter)">{{ contact.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Forgive the poor formatting - never could get code right here. ;) There is a CodePen for this here: https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/LdGEOr?editors=1011